# Ubuntu 18.04.03 cannot hibernate

Tags: linux, hibernate, ubuntu-18.04, swap

I am using a swap partition of 10.5GB (almost) while RAM of my system is 8GB. My

> /etc/fstab

file looks like this

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=19ea5c3c-94ff-4678-a071-f2990aac9191 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=C6C7-F14C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
UUID=9dab264a-b79a-42bc-affb-5b541ffaa057         none       swap     defaults    0   0
# /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4C3886483886314E /mnt/Data auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

swap is automatically mounted on boot (works fine)
when I execute the command

> sudo pm-hibernate

It waits for sometime then pc shuts down (which is good).
The problem starts when I boot it after the whole process.
It does not continue where I left.
It just boots like it does without above process.

I also created a file

> /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla

and added this in the file

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

But it does not seem to do anything.
Can anyone tell me how to hibernate ubuntu 18.04.3?
I want it to automatically hibernate on critically low battery level and also after 1 hour long hybrid-sleep/suspend/sleep.
My laptop is Dell Vostro 14-3468.
Plz, help guys...

Comment: If you are using Secure Boot, then hibernation is disabled as a security risk. I have this problem, and I don't want to disable Secure Boot, but I don't think there is another solution. (Note, I haven't verified that hibernation works with Secure Boot disabled.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is partially solved.
I just needed to add

> resume=UUID={UUID of swap partition)

in kernel parameters in general section of grub-customizer.
I also installed a gnome extension 'Hibernate status button' for easy hibernation.